# How to migrate react-redux-firebase 2.x to react-redux-firebase 3.x

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, react-redux-firebase

I am transferring to react-redux-firebase 3.x
I am studying react with this tutorial.
https://github.com/ayush221b/MarioPlan-react-redux-firebase-app

How should I migrate the following codes?

index.js

```
const store = createStore(rootReducer, 
  compose(
  applyMiddleware(thunk.withExtraArgument({getFirebase,getFirestore})),
  reduxFirestore(fbConfig),
  reactReduxFirebase(fbConfig, {useFirestoreForProfile: true, userProfile: 'users', attachAuthIsReady: true}) 
  )
);
```

I found this document.
https://react-redux-firebase.com/docs/v3-migration-guide.html
I am rebuilding the project while referencing.
However , I faced some issues.
I don't know where this firebase comes from.
Is fffConfig a common firebase-config?

reactReduxFirebase(firebase, rrfConfig)

fbconfig.js

```
  // Your web app's Firebase configuration
  // For Firebase JS SDK v7.20.0 and later, measurementId is optional
  var firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "",
    authDomain: "",
    databaseURL: "",
    projectId: "",
    storageBucket: "",
    messagingSenderId: "",
    appId: "1:12345:web:12345",
    measurementId: "G-6MGBT"
  };
  // Initialize Firebase
  firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
  firebase.firestore();

export default firebase;
```

https://github.com/ayush221b/MarioPlan-react-redux-firebase-app/blob/master/src/index.js

The code I modified

```
const rrfConfig = {
  userProfile: 'users',
  useFirestoreForProfile: true, // Firestore for Profile instead of Realtime DB
  attachAuthIsReady: true
}

 const rrfProps = {
     fbConfig,
     config: rrfConfig,
     dispatch: store.dispatch,
     createFirestoreInstance // <- needed if using firestore
  }



ReactDOM.render(
<React.StrictMode>
  <Provider store = {store}>
        <ReactReduxFirebaseProvider {...rrfProps}>
          <App />
       </ReactReduxFirebaseProvider>
  </Provider>
</React.StrictMode>
,document.getElementById('root')
```

The error

```
TypeError: Cannot read property '_' of undefined
createFirebaseInstance
src/createFirebaseInstance.js:38
  35 | }
  36 | 
  37 | // Add internal variables to firebase instance
> 38 | const defaultInternals = {
     | ^  39 |   watchers: {},
  40 |   listeners: {},
  41 |   callbacks: {},
```

Comment: Hi, the error you are getting is being thrown in the line 38 of you code which we don't see to which of the code you posted correspond. But maybe [this article](http://net-informations.com/js/iq/unerror.htm#:~:text=JavaScript%20TypeError%20is%20thrown%20when,method%20on%20an%20undefined%20object%20.) that explains your error is useful to debug your code.

Answer (score 1):

When upgrading from v2 to v3 you want to remove the two store enhancers `reduxFirestore` and `reactReduxFirebase`.  Instead you want to add a `ReactReduxFirebaseProvider` component between the Redux `Provider` and the `App`.  This provider component needs [certain props](https://react-redux-firebase.com/docs/api/ReactReduxFirebaseProvider.html):

- [required] props.config: `object` react-redux-firebase config
- [required] props.dispatch: `Function` Redux's dispatch function
- [required] props.firebase: `object` Firebase library
- [optional] props.initializeAuth: `boolean` Whether or not to initialize auth
- [optional] props.createFirestoreInstance: `Function` Function for creating extended firestore instance

The [Migration Guide](https://react-redux-firebase.com/docs/v3-migration-guide.html#remove-store-enhancer) creates the props as a separate object `rrfProps` and then passes them to the provider like `<ReactReduxFirebaseProvider {...rrfProps}>`, but you can also just set the props on the provider directly.

> I don't know where this firebase comes from. Is fffConfig a common firebase-config?

In the demo app that you linked to, the `fbConfig` (firebase config) is defined in a file [`./config/fbConfig.js`](https://github.com/ayush221b/MarioPlan-react-redux-firebase-app/blob/master/src/config/fbConfig.js) but it's not exported.  The `rrfConfig` (react redux firebase config) is the object that they are passing as the second argument to `reactReduxFirebase` in [`index.js`](https://github.com/ayush221b/MarioPlan-react-redux-firebase-app/blob/27fd349965c22fd0af5755bc6853ca9240858d4e/src/index.js#L18).  The firebase instance is initialized at the end of the `./config/fbConfig.js` file.  The naming is misleading because the variable `fbConfig` in `index.js` is actually the *store* not the config object. But the prop that you are setting is named `firebase`, so your `rrfProps` should be:

```
const rrfProps = {
  firebase: fbConfig,
...
```

But honestly I would rename this import instead.

```
import firebase from './config/fbConfig'
```

And I find it clearer to pass props inline.  So my revised code for the `index.js` file is:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import "./index.css";
import App from "./App";
import * as serviceWorker from "./serviceWorker";
import { createStore, applyMiddleware, compose } from "redux";
import rootReducer from "./store/reducers/rootReducer";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import thunk from "redux-thunk";
import {
  getFirebase,
  ReactReduxFirebaseProvider,
  createFirestoreInstance
} from "react-redux-firebase";
import firebase from "./config/fbConfig";

const store = createStore(
  rootReducer,
  compose(
    applyMiddleware(
      thunk.withExtraArgument({
        getFirebase,
        getFirestore: () => getFirebase().firestore()
      })
    )
  )
);

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <ReactReduxFirebaseProvider
      firebase={firebase}
      config={{
        useFirestoreForProfile: true,
        userProfile: "users",
        attachAuthIsReady: true
      }}
      dispatch={store.dispatch}
      createFirestoreInstance={createFirestoreInstance}
    >
      <App />
    </ReactReduxFirebaseProvider>
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);

serviceWorker.register();
```

I've explained the changes to the thunk in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66537232/10431574).

Hopefully that works.  I'm not getting any compiler errors but I haven't tested the whole login/authentication flow.

[Code Sandbox Link](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-redux-firebase-updated-to-v3-z3len?file=/src/index.js)